# I don't think that my array is storing and data

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and I am taking a college course right now. I was just curious what I am missing to give myself an output because right now the console is blank.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double avgScore;
    int highestScore, count = 0;
    String highScoringStudent;

    String names[] = null;
    int scores[] = null;

    File myFile = new File("Student_Data.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    inFile.nextLine();

    while(inFile.hasNext()) {

        for(int i = 0; i > 0; i++) {
            names[i] = inFile.next();
            scores[i] = inFile.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Name             Score");
    System.out.print(names[count] + "             " + scores[count]);
}
```

Comment: Take a careful look at `for(int i = 0; i > 0; i++)`. What could be wrong with it?

Comment: After you find that problem, here are answers for your next question: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I really wouldn't suggest to place a `for` inside a `while` loop, especially in this case (because it doesn't work). Here are the problems:

1) Your `for` loop starts with *i = 0*, and finishes right away, because *!(i > 0)* (i is not > 0) - so you are right, no data will be stored in the array!

2) Inside your `for` loop, you are reading a string, then an int one by one. After you have read them, you should move to the next string and integer to store in the next position of `names` and `score`.

3) You are not increasing i: so (if the `for` was working), you would just keep assigning different values to the array, at the same position (basically resetting the value of a variable every time).

This would be the best code that would work for your case:

```
int i = 0;

while(inFile.hasNext()) {
   names[i] = inFile.next();
   scores[i] = inFile.nextInt();
   count++;
   i++;
}
```

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: @Superbia also be sure to tell me if it works or not!